# How to adjust color in KDE scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar, kde-plasma

I wrote a program to plot oscilloscope data and make a KDE scatter plot with a colorbar. Unfortunately it requires a third party lib (readTrc) as well as the oscilloscope binary [file](https://ufile.io/ru90tpel) which size is 200MB. The [lib](https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/readTrc) can be found on github.

```
import pandas as pd
import readTrc
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

trcpath = 'filename.trc'    #Binary Oscilloscope File (200 MB)
datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc(trcpath)
srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)
df = df.abs()               #Build Dataframe from above file

fig = plt.figure()

#Eliminate Noise
df[df < 3] = None
df = df.dropna()

#x and y axes data to plot
q1 = np.array(df[1].tolist()[:-2])
q2 = np.array(df[1].tolist()[1:-1])
q3 = np.array(df[1].tolist()[2:])
dq1 = q2 - q1
dq2 = q3 - q2

#Create first Dataset
qqstack = []
xy = np.vstack([dq1,dq2])

#Determine max value for colorbar (highest repeating x/y combination)
df_d = pd.DataFrame([dq1,dq2]).T
for idx, row in df_d.iterrows():
    if row[0] == row[1]:
        qqstack.append((row[0], row[1]))
cbar_max = collections.Counter(qqstack).most_common(1)[0][-1]

#sort to show most present values last
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)
idx = z.argsort()
x, y, z = dq1[idx], dq2[idx], z[idx]

#plot graph
plt.scatter(x, y,
            c=z,
            s=20,
            cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'))

#create colormap variable
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'),
                           norm = matplotlib.colors.PowerNorm(vmin = -0.1, vmax = cbar_max, gamma = 1))
sm._A = []

fig.colorbar(sm, ticks = range(0, cbar_max, 250))
plt.grid(zorder = 0, alpha = 0.3)
plt.xlabel('dq1 / mV')
plt.ylabel('dq2 / mV')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I adjust the color allocation in the plot? I want there to be less blue space so the transition is visible more, like on this graph:

[image]

Comment: the reference image seems to be using a logarithmic colormap. Maybe `LogNorm` could help...

Comment: I think you should try to come up with a minimum working example, you could maybe generate some data sampling from 2d gaussians? I don't think the issue is in the trc file loading anyway

Comment: @filippo I've tried `LogNorm` already but the only thing that changes is the colorbar legend. The color behaviour stays the same.

Comment: @filippo This seems to be a problem with my data. The majority of datapoints seem to have a density of 1 (or slightly more). I guess this problem can't be solved by kde. The data seems to be represented correctly although not very apparent

Comment: about, the first comment, not that you should normalize both the colorbar and the scatterplot colormap in the same way, at least I'm guessing, I could help better if you could provide some sample toy dataset